# For setHTML() method, is it still safe If we do not use Safehtml but we validate the String & only accept some limited html tag (Gwt)?

Tags: html, gwt

Any widget that has setHTML method could give a hole in security system, but if we validate String & only accept some limited html tags such as `<b>, <i>...`. And then we put this string into setHTML method.

Then my question is "is it still safe if we do that"
For example, we check the String text to make sure it only contain some limited html tags `<b>, </b>, <i>, </i>..`. If the string text contain other tags then we won't let uses to input that text. Then we use:
    `html1.setHTML(text);`  instead of `html1.setHTML(SafeHtmlUtils.fromString(text))`

i don't know why `html1.setHTML(SafeHtmlUtils.fromString(text))` does not generate the formatted text, it just shows plain text when i run it in eclipse? For example

```
html1.setHTML(SafeHtmlUtils.fromString("<b>text</b>"))
```

will have plain text result `<b>text</b>` instead of bold text "**text**" with correct html format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to *sanitize* the html, not escape it. The `fromString` method is meant to *escape* the string - if a user types enters `a < b`, but forgets the space, then adds `>c`, you don't want the c to be bold and the b to be missing entirely. Escaping is done to actually render the string that is given, assuming it is text.

On the complete other end of the spectrum, you can use `fromTrustedString` which tells GWT that you absolutely trust the source of the data, and that you will allow it to do anything. This typically should not be done for any data that comes from the user.

Somewhere off to the side of all of the then we have *sanitation*, the process where you take a string that is *meant* to be HTML, and ensure it is safe, rather than either treating it like text, or trusting it implicitly. This is hard to do well - any tag that has a `style` attribute could potentially attack you (this is why GWT has `SafeStyle` like `SafeHtml`, any tag that has a uri, url or href could be used to attack (hence `SafeUri`), and any attribute that the browser treats as a callback such as `onclick` or the like can be used to run JavaScript. The `HtmlSanitizer` type is meant to be able to do this.

There is a built-in implementation of this, as of at least GWT 2.4 - `SimpleHtmlSanitizer`. This class whitelists certain html tags, including your `<b>` and `<i>` tags, as well as a few others. Attributes are completely removed, as there are too many cases where they might not be safe. As the class name suggests, this is just a simple approach to this problem - a more complex and in-depth approach might be more true to the original code, but this also comes with the risk of allowing unsafe HTML content.

Comment: Thax for your answer, but why the output of html1.setHTML(SafeHtmlUtils.fromString("<b>text</b>")) is plain text? Output of the above code is: "<b>text</b>" & there no formatted text? The it really confused me why we need afeHtmlUtils.fromString?? since i want safehtml but i also want the result to have correct html formatted text not just plain text.

Comment: The answer is in the first paragraph - the content `"a<b>c"` might be bad html or it might be hard to read text, just like someone might've deliberately written `"<b>text</b>"` and not meant it to look like html - code doesn't know. Once it becomes `SafeHtml`, it should be clear which was meant. You make that distinction _for_ it by selecting `SafeHtmlUtils.fromString` meaning 'it is just a string', `SafeHtmlUtils.fromTrustedString` meaning 'it is html, and known safe', or `HtmlSanitizer.sanitize` meaning 'it is html, and might not be safe'.

Comment: But you have not answered me. Why the out put of "html1.setHTML(SafeHtmlUtils.fromString("<b>text</b>"))" is plain text "<b>text</b>" (no bold text) & not formmated text. If it is formatted text then the text should be bold. 

This very simple question why everyone avoids to answer it, i don't know why?

Comment: Finaly I fixed, i have to use SafeHtmlUtils.fromSafeConstant, then the result will be html-formatted text. Thax u anyway

Comment: No one is avoiding, you aren't understanding the answer. If I, as a user who doesn't know HTML, want to write "a<b", I expect to see those characters. SafeHtmlUtils.fromString is designed to make sure that those show up. If you want it to render as if it were html, do not use that - its that simple. You have two choices then - if you *trust your data*, then use fromTrustedString, and if you are getting data from the user, use sanitize instead.

Comment: I fully understood now. Thax you very much